Need to include functionality for arrows on a news section that has different displays on different screen sizes
I have a News section that maps through an array of data. Currently I only have 3 news items in my array. On larger screens, 3 news Items show meaning all my data is showed. However, on MobileScreens, I only want 1 newsItem to show which is when the arrow functionality needs to come into play. My major problem is figuring this out. I can't seem to isolate the functionality to only work on mobile screens without affecting the layout on the desktop screen. I don't mind the functionality working on desktop screens incase I add more data in the future, but it shouldn't work at the moment as all the data is being shown on larger screens. So for the moment, the arrow functionality should only work on mobile screens.
FYI I haven't added css for the mobile screen as I'm not sure how I would do this without inputting the arrow functionality first (i assume I shouldn't display: none two news Items on smaller screens as this may mess with the arrow functionality)
Here is the code for reference, appreciate any help.
import React from 'react';
import styles from './page.module.scss';
import { StaticImageData } from 'next/image';
import { recentNewsData } from '@/app/assets/constants/data';

interface RecentNewsProps {
  id: number;
  image: StaticImageData;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  date: string;
}

const RecentNews = () => {
  const renderNewsItem = (news: RecentNewsProps) => {
    const { id, image, title, description, date } = news;

    let itemClassName = styles.newsItem;
    if (id === 1) {
      itemClassName = styles.newsItemWide;
    }

    return (
      <div key={id} className={itemClassName}>
        <div className={styles.newsItem__container}>
          <img src={image.src} alt="" className={styles.newsItem__image}/>
          <div className={styles.newsItem__content}>
            <div className={styles.newsItem__title}>{title}</div>
            <div className={styles.newsItem__description}>{description}</div>
            <div className={styles.newsItem__date}>
              <img src="/calender.png" alt="" />
              <span>{date}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.RecentNews}>
      <div className={styles.RecentNews__topBar}>
        <div className={styles.sectionTitle}>RECENT NEWS</div>
        <div className={styles.arrow__container}>
          <img src="/recent-news-arrow-left.png" alt="" />
          <img src="/recent-news-arrow-right.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.newsGrid}>{recentNewsData.map((news) => renderNewsItem(news))}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecentNews;

@import './../../assets/styles/config';

.RecentNews {
  padding: 3rem 9rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;

  @include MobileScreen {
    padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
  }
}

.RecentNews__topBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow__container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;

  @include MobileScreen {
    gap: 6px;
  }
}

.arrow__container img {
  width: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;

  @include MobileScreen {
    width: 30px;
  }
}

.sectionTitle {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #193043;

  @include MobileScreen {
    font-size: 32px; // For global styles
  }
}

.newsGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
}

.newsItemWide {
  grid-column: span 2;

  @include MobileScreen {
    grid-column: span 1;
  }
}

.newsItem {
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.newsItem,
.newsItemWide {
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.newsItem__image {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}

.newsItem .newsItem__image {
  height: 200px;
}

.newsItem__content {
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.newsItem__title {
  color: #193043;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.newsItem__description {
  color: #747d82;
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.newsItem__date {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 11px;
}

.newsItem__date span {
  color: #c7c7c7;
}

.newsItem__date img {
  width: 20px;
}

Essentially 3 news items on display on larger screens and only 1 news item on mobile screens. So when the user clicks on an arrow the next news item should show.
Appreciate the assistance.
Tried updating index state with handlePrevNews and handleNextNews functions but it didn't work and messed up the whole section.

Is your code supposed to already do something different on mobile? Can you add code for the approach you're having issues with?
